# ap_log_perror unable to read loglevel from configuration file?

Tags: apache, logging, apache2, error-logging

```
Loglevel error
```

I am giving this in the configuration file,httpd.conf file,when i am using the function ap_log_rerror,it is capturing only log messages that are having error or above loglevels,but when i am using the function ap_log_perror function it is showing log messages starting from default loglevel warn,i cannot understand why in the case of ap_log_perror it is not reading the loglevel from configuration ?
why i am unable achieve the same with ap_log_perror ?

Answer (score 0):

ap_log_perror would not read from the configuration file,i made changes in the code log.c,in order to do so and added a function there that reads the config file loglevel,after reading loglevel from configuration file ,it is assigned to the default_loglevel declared in log.c file and thus, can work.

Cheers!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724041/apache-modules-ap-log-perror-is-at-a-different-level-than-ap-log-error has a link to an apache bug report